# vsforce.retriveCommand not found

Tags: apex, visualforce, vs-code

I am new to Salesforce.

I installed VSCode and added some plugins then installed vforce plugin as shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=271&v=XD1BqLErWUQ) video.

I have the following plugins installed:

[image]

When I try to run command in command platte:

[image]

I get the below issue:

[image]

I have set up the user name, password and token in the user settings.

What can be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the legacy [vsforce package](https://github.com/coveo/vsforce), which has not been developed for two years, if you've also installed the Salesforce DX CLI package.

SFDX already supports retrieval and deployment of Metadata API packages using the [`force:mdapi:retrieve`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_mdapi.htm#!) and `force:mdapi:deploy` commands, even without using a Dev Hub or SFDX source format.

Additionally, [pre-release versions](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/wiki/Develop-Against-Any-Org-in-Visual-Studio-Code) of SFDX and the extensions for VS Code support development against non-scratch orgs using a Metadata API `package.xml` with SFDX-format source code.